# AD group not recognized in TFS

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to add AD groups in TFS. Currently our TFS server version is TFS2013.4.

ct\PERAT2_ROLE_IS_Application_Support_org

- Able to add in TFS without any issues.
- Group scope = Global
- Group type = Security
- NOT mail-enabled

ct\perat2_role_abu_imps_offshore_sp_org

- Having issue while adding in TFS, below is the error which we are receiving.
- Group scope = Universal
- Type = Security
- mail-enabed

**TF400067: Unable to find or resolve the identity.**

Does it mean only the Globadl scope groups can be added? how to identify which level scope groups can be added in to our server? Please advice

Comment: Can you add the users directly which in the Universal scope groups?

Comment: Yes, able to add the users directly in the universal scope group but not the group in TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the message TFS cannot find the identity. So, you need to check the [Domain Trusts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253081(v=vs.100).aspx#Domain%20Trusts). The types of trust that can be employed **depend on the forest and domain types that are deployed in your company’s network**.

Generally, Team Foundation Server users and services must be authenticated so that they can access server components. From a trust relationship point of view, Team Foundation Server must trust the domain where the user or service account is defined.

In your scenario, make sure the Group scope type doesn't affect that. Refer to [Group scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755692(v=ws.10).aspx) to see the differents.

So, you can try to change the group scope from **Universal/Domain local** to **global**. If that works, that means the Globadl scope groups works only for you.

Comment: Thank you, will check on this.

Comment: Yes, the issue has been resoolved after the group scope was changed to Global. Thanks so much!!